# Length of dispersal flight of European spruce bark beetle?

Tags: entomology, ecology

I'm interested in length of dispersal flight of *Ips typographus*. I can barely find some information about dispersal distances, height of dispersal flight, but not at all information about how many days does it takes for one beetle to find suitable host in average? The only information I found is that it is highly variable (Forsse, E., & Solbreck, C. 1985. Migration in the bark beetle ips-typographus duration timing and height of flight. Z. Angew. Entomol. 100 (1). 47-57). I also know that it is weather dependent but this won't help me... thank you !!

Comment: You should check out this recent dissertation, which might contain useful information: [Kärvemo. 2015. *Outbreak dynamics of the spruce bark beetle Ips typographus in time and space*](http://pub.epsilon.slu.se/12015/).

Comment: thanks @fileunderwater! I didn't know about this one !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of days may still be unknown, and it is probably a large variation when they find a suitable host tree. The "pioneer males" might use "random-walks", when they try several trees before they chose the right one. Its also a large difference between endemic and epidemic periods regarding dispersals.

Anyhow, the flight distance of I.t. has been shown to be more than 8 km (see [Botterweg, 1982](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1439-0418.1982.tb02594.x/pdf)), but during outbreaks when it can be pheromone sources everywhere most of them may disperse less than 500 m and maybe even less than 100 m. See:

Kautz. 2011. Quantifying spatio-temporal dispersion of bark beetle infestations in epidemic and non-epidemic conditions.

[Whichmann and Ravn. 2001. The spread of Ips typographus (L.) (Coleoptera, Scolytidae) attacks following heavy windthrow in Denmark, analysed using GIS](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378112700004771)

and as mentioned above, the [dissertation by Kärvemo](http://pub.epsilon.slu.se/12015/) and articles within.

I hope this helps.

cheers

Simon

Comment: Hi @SimonKärvemo, thank you very much for the answer and for the proposition of different papers. I hoped to obtain a type of answer as "10 days" or similar but I was sure that it will not be so simple... I am working with Kautz's paper but they simply establish that the flight  takes "several days". I also wanted to relate it to IT life cycle but this is highly variable too ( from 7 - 11 weeks - it is almost the double ! - to establish the threshold value). So, it still remains unknown... but I feel much more sure about this information now ! :)